# Simple Form: disabling fields conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, dry

I'm using `simple_form`. I'm wondering what the best practice for disabling a field conditionally (in my case, depending on params) would be ? I got it to work like this:

```
= simple_form_for @company do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  - if params.has_key?(:name)
    = f.input :name, input_html: { value: params[:name] }, disabled: true
  - else    
    = f.input :name, input_html: { value: params[:name] }
    = f.button :submit
```

but it doesn't seem too neat, so I was wondering if you have any suggestions on how to refactor it?

Comment: Try `= f.input :name, input_html: { value: params[:name] }, disabled: params.has_key?(:name)`

Comment: Thanks, that does it for me :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)